# LSTM with autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

I am trying to wrap my head around when to use LSTM with an autoencoder and when to use one without.

Does anyone have a good rule of thumb of when to use a LSTM with an autoencoder?
I am not trying to be overly broad just a classes of problems that this solves.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs are generally applied to sequential data, like time series or music scores (...). Autoencoders on the other hand learn efficient data encodings in order to e.g. classify images - or more precisely determine a specific occurrence or non-occurrence. One example could be to determine if an image actually shows a car or not (...).
LSTMs combined with Autoencoders could be applied for anomaly detection. If data can't be autoencoded accordingly it most likely represents an outlier [data sequence]. LSTMs alone could be used to predict the next value(s) in a time series.

Next time use 'Data Science Stack Exchange' - you'll get more informed answers.